# Does any Riemannian manifold admit Ricci flow and Ricci soliton?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I started studying Ricci flow and Ricci soliton (personally) and I have read some basic content of Ricci flow. I want to know the following:

> 1. Does any Riemannian manifold admit Ricci flow and Ricci soliton?
> 2. Is there difference between  the Ricci flow and the Ricci soliton?

Thanks.